# Identify and alert for human access to DB instance in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-aurora

I have to create an alert when a human user tries to access a DB instance in AWS using a service account. Programmatic access should be fine and no need to be alerted.

Could anyone suggest a best possible solution to achieve this?

Comment: By 'a human user', do you mean access via username+password? Because a service account should only have programmatic access (access key + secret), never access via user+password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, at least not directly.

There are two ways to access an Aurora database:

- Via a TCP connection, using the Postgres or MySQL connection protocol.
- Via the [RDS Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rdsdataservice/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html).

In both cases, there is a program at the other end of the connection, and the database has no way to determine whether that program is an business application, a user-written program connecting using a connection library, a user making API calls from a Jupyter notebook, or a user typing directly into `psql`.

The best that you can get is an *indirect* indication.

For example, if you use usernames and passwords to access the database, and store that information in a Secrets Manager secret, then you can use [CloudTrail](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awscloudtrail/latest/userguide/cloudtrail-user-guide.html) to find all calls to `GetSecretValue` and alert based on user identity. You can do the same thing for `ExecuteStatement` if using the Data API, but I *don't* believe that there's a CloudTrail event if you're using [IAM-generated tokens](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html) for authorization.

However, even that has limitations. First, because you have to wait 15 minutes for events to appear in CloudTrail (which makes it a forensic tool, not a good alerting tool). Second, because there are ways to conceal your true identity (although it's not that easy with the Data API).

The *real* solution to your problem (which you have not described) will be an architecture that makes it difficult to create ad hoc database connections, *and a culture* that discourages such behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. My problem is that I have to create an alert and sent to an MS Teams channel if someone (human user) other than a process or program trying to access a particular DB instance. is there any way to get the ip address of the host who is trying to access the DB? If that is possible, I could use to filter the ip range and identify whether it is a user or a program.